# Returning a vector from a function and update the objects of the vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have 3 `Player` objects that I have passed as reference arguments in a function.
The function does the following:

1. Creates a `vector` of the 3 objects and bubble sorts the them based on their score (data members).
2. Then it checks for first, second or third ranks and returns a resized `vector`.

In `main` function, I am able to print the winner and her reward when I iterate through the `vector` but it doesn't seem to update the actual objects.  **How can I update the objects?**

This is what I have so far:

```
int enterBet(int balance, int maxBet);
vector <Player> chkWinner(Player &a, Player &b, Player &c, int pot);

bool sorting_method(Player &_1, Player &_2) {
    //Bigger numbers go first
    return _1.m_total > _2.m_total;
}

int main()
{
    Player *player1 = new Player;
    Player *player2 = new Player;
    Player *player3 = new Player;
    vector <Player> winnerArr;
    winnerArr.resize(3);
    int pot = 0;
    int betAmount = 0;
    int maxBet = 10;
    player2->m_name = "Kelly";
    player3->m_name = "Martha";
    int x, y, z;

    winnerArr[0] = *player1;
    winnerArr[1] = *player2;
    winnerArr[2] = *player3;

    sort(winnerArr.begin(), winnerArr.end(), sorting_method);
    cout << winnerArr[0].m_total << ", "
        << winnerArr[1].m_total << ", "
        << winnerArr[2].m_total << endl;

    x = winnerArr[0].m_total;
    y = winnerArr[1].m_total;
    z = winnerArr[2].m_total;

    if (x == y && x == z){
        cout << "Divide pot by 3" << endl;
        //totalArr.resize(3);
    }
    else if (x == y && x != z){
        cout << "Divide pot by 2" << endl;
        winnerArr.resize(2);

    }
    else{
        cout << "Pay full Pot" << endl;
        winnerArr.resize(1);
    }

    int payout;

    if (winnerArr.size() == 3){
        payout = ((pot * 5) / 3);
    }
    else if (winnerArr.size() == 2){
        payout = ((pot * 5) / 2);
    }
    else if (winnerArr.size() == 1){
        payout = (pot * 5);

        for (int i = 0; i < winnerArr.size(); i++){
            cout << winnerArr[i].m_name << " wins " << payout << endl;
            winnerArr[i].m_balance += payout;
            cout << winnerArr[i].m_balance << endl;

        }
    }
    cout << player1->m_name << "'s total: " << player1->m_balance << endl;
    cout << player2->m_name << "'s total: " << player2->m_balance << endl;
    cout << player3->m_name << "'s total: " << player3->m_balance << endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: You return a vector of COPIES of the players - is that what you intended? I suggest you pass a `vector<Player>&` and modify that with the new order. This also allows you to have any number of players. I suggest you use the built in sort function. What is the point of this loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand this. I tried passing a ref of vector array but it outputs 0 for al player's total.

I wish to declare the winner/s and add the reward to the actual player not his copy.

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: 1. Why are you saying `vector array`? `vector` is enough. 2. Your code does not compile. Please post a compilable code. 3. When you have rewritten the `chkWinner` function, please remove the earlier version or atleast comment it out. And show the modified `main` function also. 4. Finally, how does your `Player` class look like? Post that code too.

Comment: The method `chkWinner()`returns `void`. But the code in `main()` - `winnerArr = chkWinner(winnerArr);` is expecting a return value  !!!

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. I have posted the player class and the modified main function. hope this is compilable

Comment: gargankit, that was a copying mistake, I have modified it, thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in `sort()` method as suggested by @NeilKirk ??

Comment: The best thing to do would be to reduce the code to a minimum that allows you to reproduce the problem. Instead of `Player`, create a class with only 1 member, then right a simplified `chkWinner` function and test if that works. If not, consider asking here with that simplified example.

Comment: Why, oh man, why you create players manually?? `std::vector` can do it for you: `std::vector<Player> players(3)`. [That `(3)` tells the `vector` to have 3 defaultly-constructed elements.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Comment: I am doing that because I want to store the same players to that array. I am also resizing that array to determine the winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone pointed out, you shouldn't be creating a new array and modify the one you already have. STL give you a hand to accomplish what you want with the sort function.

Firstly, you need:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Then you need a sorting function:

```
bool sorting_method(const Player &_1, const Player &_2){
    //Bigger numbers go first
    return _1.m_total > _2.m_total;
}
```

Finally, you use sort instead of your chained loops:

```
void chkWinner(std::vector <Player> &totalArr){
    sort(totalArr.begin(), totalArr.end(), sorting_method);
    // Add code here, if you need to perform something else. 
    //totalArr is already in the order you need it to.
{
```

[More information about `std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/)

EDIT: I modified the code to create an array with pointers to Players instead of copies of the players.

```
bool sorting_method(Player *_1, Player *_2) {
    //Bigger numbers go first
    return _1->m_total > _2->m_total;
}

int main()
{
    Player *player1 = new Player(2, 1);
    Player *player2 = new Player(5 ,2);
    Player *player3 = new Player(3, 3);
    vector <Player *> winnerArr(3);
    int pot = 0;
    int betAmount = 0;
    int maxBet = 10;
    int x, y, z;

    winnerArr[0] = player1;
    winnerArr[1] = player2;
    winnerArr[2] = player3;

    sort(winnerArr.begin(), winnerArr.end(), sorting_method);
    cout << winnerArr[0]->m_name << ", "
        << winnerArr[1]->m_name << ", "
        << winnerArr[2]->m_name << endl;
```

Please note that because of that change you'll have to modify all the code that tries to access the array, including the sorting_method. This code I wrote is already modified, so you just need to modify the rest of it. I removed the resize function and added the (3) parameter when creating the array. I believe its simpler and clear. Have fun :D

Comment: Hi, I have rewritten the code with the std:sort. But it still does not update the player.m_total outside the array. It seems like the vector array holds different players than the actually ones.

Comment: @Chintan I probably misunderstood what you wanted in the first place. Do you want change the values inside the objects? If so, why? It looks like each one of them is a player, you would be messing up those values. What I wrote in my answer was designed to sort the array only, without changing each member.

Comment: so, there are 3 players (1 Player + 2 AI). Each player has a 'm_balance' member variable. All players bet before the game and then the winner wins the entire pot. So the sort algorithm helps me find the winner and then I add the pot value to the winners 'm_balance'. I am able to derive the winner but unable to add the pot value to their 'm_balance' variable

Comment: @Chintan I think I found the problem. When you create the array, you are actually copying your players, instead of passing a reference to them. After that you modify the copy and the originals stay intact. I'll change my answer to the new code I wrote.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It finally worked but I am still not sure what does the '*' in this syntax do.
vector <Player *> winnerArr(3);

Anyways, thank you every one, I learnt a lot.

Comment: @Chintan the * means "address of": it's a pointer. What we are doing is to make arrays with the locations in memory of your player classes.

Comment: thanks SlySherZ.
here is a thread that could help other reading this post. It explains the concept
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624819/c-vector-of-objects-vs-vector-of-pointers-to-objects